# How to print a value outside a for loop in scala?

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and would like to know way to access val which is defined inside for loop and would like to write that val to a file outside for loop.

```
def time[A](logFile: String, description: String)(job: => A): Unit = {
    var totalDuration: Long = 0

    for (i <- 1 to 3) {
        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis
        val result = job
        val finalTime = System.currentTimeMillis
        val duration = finalTime - currentTime

        totalDuration = if (totalDuration == 0) duration else totalDuration.min(duration)   
    }

    val pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(logFile),true)) 
    pw.write(description + " " + result + " " + totalDuration +" ms"+"\n")
    pw.flush()
    pw.close
}
```

In the above code i am calculating my result which contains the length of bytes read from other function and would like to calculate the time it takes to read the total bytes. I would like to iterate 3 times and take the minimum of all the three. The val result contains the bytes length which also needs to be written in a file. i get a error because i am accessing the result val outside the scope of for loop. Can someone please help me solve this error. How can i access the val result outside for loop to write it to a file ?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your question is answered, the for loop is not in it's typical form, which would look more like this:

```
def time[A] (logFile: String, description: String) (job: => A): Unit = {
    val (result, totalDuration): (A, Long) = (for { i <- 1 to 3 
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis
        result = job
        finalTime = System.currentTimeMillis
        duration = finalTime - currentTime 
    } yield (result, duration)).minBy {case (r, d) => d} 

    val pw = new PrintWriter (new FileOutputStream (new File (logFile), true)) 
    pw.write (description + " " + result + " " + totalDuration +" ms"+"\n")
    pw.flush()
    pw.close
}
```

If I understood your code correctly. I don't know whether a side effect yields to different results for each job invocation. 
I missed the internal discussion of the for-loop invention/definition, why the keyword `val` should be omitted here, but it is quiet handy.

What is more important, is, that you usually have all temporary assignments in the `for (...(here part)...) { not here}`. The consequences of round or curly braces in the first part aren't totally clear to me, but if you use round parens, you have terminate most statements with a semicolon.

```
scala> for (i <-  1 to 3;
     | j <- 4 to 5;
     | k = j-i;
     | l = k/2) yield l * l; 
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1)
```

Note that neither i, nor j, k, l where declared as val or var.

```
scala> for {i <-  1 to 3
     | j <- 4 to 5
     | k = j-i
     | l = k/2} yield l * l; 
res3: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1)
```

You will find multiple questions here, which explain, how a for-loop is and can be translatet to a flatMap/map-combination, eventually with filter:

```
scala> for {i <-  1 to 3
     | j <- 4 to 5
     | k = j-i
     | if (k > 1) 
     | l = k/2 } yield l * l; 
res5: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 4, 1, 1, 1)
```

And instead of yielding just one value, you can yield a tuple, and assign by

```
 val (a:X, b:Y) = (for ..... yield (aa, bb))
```

The

```
yield (result, duration)).minBy {case (r, d) => d}
```

takes a tuple (result, duration) and selects the minimum by duration, but yields both values.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it very briefly...:)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **yield**. Yield will return data from for loop after completion of loop and use that data accordingly. Since I do not have your code. see this example

```
val j = for (i <- 1 to 10) yield i
println(j)
```

output of j will be

```
Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

For replacing your for loop to calculate the total duration of some jobs that are executed sequentially, you could use `foldLeft`

Answer (score 0):

Make use of yield or you can use any of the fold method. Or if you are good with recursion you can use a tailrec method which returns what is Desired. Yield is the most simplest way to do it.

```
val answer = for(i<- 1 to 10) yield i 
println(answer) // Vector(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```